# z-index issue with YouTube iFrame (in full screen mode)

Tags: css, iframe, youtube, embed, z-index

wondered if anyone can shed some light...

If you watch the video in full-screen mode on this page: http://singtonicity.com.gridhosted.co.uk/ you'll notice some elements float on top of the video (to view in fullscreen mode double-click the video whilst it's playing).

I am assuming this is to do with the classic iFrame/z-index issue but I just can't find away round this one.

I am wondering if it's anything to do with the default styling browsers give to iframes in full screen eg: `iframe:-webkit-full-screen`???

Any help is most welcome.

Thanks in advance

Richard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually to do with the opacity and the animation you have. Try removing the `fadein ease-in-out 1` CSS animation and check the result.

Take a look at this excellent article from Phillip Walton, should help clear a few things up: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: First off - really sorry for the belated response - I moved house and things kids went crazy!

Thank you - This has solved the problem and thanks for the link - very worth reading! :)

Answer (score 4):

I had such problem in Safari browser. Needed to remove `will-change` css property from parent element to fix it.